# Почему mMap.getMyLocation возвращает null?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api

Пытаюсь получить lat и lng из GoogleMapы. В переменную типа Location кидаю mMap.getMyLocation. Но это переменная null, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private Location mLocation = null;

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker myPos;

private int speed = 0 ;
private TextView speedView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    speedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedView);

    /*Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);*/

}

public void requestPermission(String strPermission, int perCode, Context _c, Activity _a){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(_a,strPermission)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS permissions dont allow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_a,new String[]{strPermission},perCode);
    }
}

public static boolean checkPermission(String strPermission,Context _c,Activity _a){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(_c, strPermission);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Toast.makeText(_c, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Denied, You cannot access location data.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23){
        if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getApplicationContext(), this)) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

            mLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
            if (mLocation != null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,getApplicationContext(),this);
        }
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо дать разрешения(`permissions`) в манифесте + для проишивок `6.0 ++` надо получать разрешения вручную

Вот пример :

**Объявлять, где вы используете Oncreate или другие**

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){


    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,getApplicationContext(),this)) {
    //You fetch the Location here

    //code to use the 
    }
    else
    {
    requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION,getApplicationContext(),this);
    }

    }
```

**Также объявить в классе**

```
 public static void requestPermission(String strPermission,int perCode,Context _c,Activity _a){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(_a,strPermission)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_a,new String[]{strPermission},perCode);
        }
    }

public static boolean checkPermission(String strPermission,Context _c,Activity _a){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(_c, strPermission);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

    case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION:
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        fetchLocationData();

        } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Denied, You cannot access location data.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        break;

    }
}
```

B всё и не забыть в манифесте добавить

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Измени у себя в коде это

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
```

на от это

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){


if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,getApplicationContext(),this)) {
//You fetch the Location here

//code to use the 
}
else
{
requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION,getApplicationContext(),this);
}

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67030/discussion-on-answer-by-elik--mmap-getmylocation--null).